# How to bind the values of two types of inputs to a single array in Vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

In a web form, using Vuejs, I would like to implement a multiple choice question with a sub-question for each item.

For instance, the question could look like this:

> What type of vehicle do you use, and how often ?
>
> A) Aeroplane (chekbox), Every day / Once a month / once a year (radio),
>
> B) Train (checkbox), Every day / Once a month / Once a year (radio),
>
> C) Donkey (checkbox), Every day / Once a month / Once a year (radio),
>
> D) (and so on).

I can imagine that my html could look something like this :

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="line" v-for="(type, index) in listOfVehicles">
                        <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="index" v-bind:id="index" v-model="???">
                        <label v-bind:for="index">{{type}}</label>

                        <div class="subquestion" v-for="(sub, id) in listOfSubQuestions">
                            <input type="radio" 
                                   v-bind:value="id" 
                                   v-bind:id="'sub-' + index + '-' + id"
                                   v-model="???">
                            <label v-bind:for="'sub-' + index + '-' + id">{{sub}}</label>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

where my Vue instance would have `listOfVehicles` and `listOfSubQuestions` as arrays in my data. 
Ideally, I would like all the respondent's input to be stored in a single array called for instance `answers`.

As an example, if answers A and C have been ticked, answers could look something like: `[{vehicle: 'A', frequency: 'Once a year'},{vehicle: 'C', frequency: 'Every day'}]`.

But I have no clue how to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made something if this is what you need. Its my first time answering a question hope this can help you out. **You can add a button and store a new object every-time you click the button,
 which can result something like the example you mentioned.**

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    vehicle: [],
    frequency: '',
    result: []
  },
  methods: {
   save() {
     const result = {
       vehicle: this.vehicle,
        frequency: this.frequency
      }
      this.result.push(result)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>What type of vehicle do you use, and how often ?</h2>
  
  <div>
      <label for="plane">Aeroplane</label>
      <input id="plane" type="checkbox" value="aeroplane" v-model="vehicle">
      <label for="car">car</label>
      <input id="car" type="checkbox" value="car" v-model="vehicle">
      <label for="train">train</label>
      <input id="train" type="checkbox" value="train" v-model="vehicle">
      
      <div>
        <label for="plane">everyday</label>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="everyday" v-model="frequency">
        <label for="plane">monthly</label>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="monthly " v-model="frequency">
        <label for="plane">yearly</label>
        <input type="radio" name="options" value="yearly" v-model="frequency">
      </div>
      
      <button @click="save">submit</button>
      
      <p>{{result}}</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to store a frequency for each selected vehicle. Your solution doesn't seem to do that unfortunately.